# Factorizing $x^2-bxy+cy^2$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

If $x^2-bx+c=(x+p)(x-q)$ ,then, factorise $x^2-bxy+cy^2$.

My attempt -  $(x+p)(x-q)=x^2+px-qx-pq$

$\implies p-q=b $ and $pq=c$

similarly-$p'-q'=by$ and $p'q'=cy^2$(assuming that on factorising $x^2-bxy+cy^2$ the result is $(x+p')(x-q')$ ).What to do next?

Comment: Can you see a simple way of finding values of $p', q'$ closely related to $p, q$?

Comment: @MarkBennet sorry but i am still not able to get it.Can you please send it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with
$$x^2-bx+c=(x+p)(x-q)$$
Now replace $x$ by $\frac{x}{y}$
$$\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2-b\frac{x}{y}+c=(\frac{x}{y}+p)(\frac{x}{y}-q)$$
now multiply by $y^2$ to get
$$x^2-bxy+cy^2=(x+py)(x-qy)$$

Comment: can you please explain me how did you get the idea of replacing $x$ by $\frac{x}{y}$?